# Is it possible to calculate percentiles in skewed distribution without raw data (only mean, median, SD)?

Tags: normal-distribution, skewness, quantiles

If it is of any one's interest, the data is taken from the duration of men "last in bed" [as studied here](https://www.jsm.jsexmed.org/article/S1743-6095(15)32276-1/pdf).

I want to calculate the percentiles (say, 95th) of a non-normal distribution without raw data. **What are the minimum constraints needed?** I have the following and I think some are not necessary.

- n=474
- mean=8.5
- SD=7.47
- median=6.0
- min=0.1
- max=52.7

Comment: There's an infinite number of possible solutions. It might be possible to derive some bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The percentile depends on the exact shape of the distribution. So unless you make a parametric assumption about the distribution or an assumption directly about the 95th percentile you cannot estimate the percentile well without the original data.